# Limit of CDFs and inverse CDFs for transformed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume that $X$ is continuous random variable with CDF $F$. Let $t$ and $t_n$ be two functions, so that the transformed random variables $t(X)$ and $t_n(X)$ are well-defined for all $n$, and that $t_n \to t$ when $n \to \infty$.

Is is true that $F_{t_n}(x) \to F_t (x)$ and that $F^{-1}_{t_n}(x) \to F^{-1}_t(x)$ when $n \to \infty$?

What are the assumptions that are needed for $t_n$ and $t$? Does it complicate matters if $t_n$ is discontinuous?

I was thinking applying (reverse) Fatou's lemma for $F_{t_n}(x) = E_x[1(t_n(X) < x)]$ but I'm unsure if there is a better argument and if this even works for the inverse CDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t_n\to t$ pointwise, for any bounded continuous function $f$,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}f(t_n(X))&=\mathsf{E}\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n(X)) \\
&=\mathsf{E}f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n(X)\right) \\
&=\mathsf{E}f(t(X))
\end{align}
by the dominated convergence theorem, which [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) that $t_n(X)\xrightarrow{d}t(X)$. As for the convergence of quantiles, see, e.g.,  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93983/convergence-in-distribution-and-convergence-of-quantile).

Comment: What's the dominating function which you use for the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @Idontgetit $f$ is bounded...

Comment: Does this hold if the convergence $t_n \to t$ is in probability?

Comment: @NPHA Yes. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374830/dominated-convergence-theorem-with-almost-surely-replaced-by-convergence-in-p